# Restoring div content on mouseout after click

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I would like the content of a DIV to change when either of these conditions is met:

- **Clicking** on a text link above the DIV
- **Hovering** over the DIV itself

The DIV content should revert to its original state when the cursor is moved away from the div or the link.

My problem is this: The DIV content does not change back to the original after the link is clicked *and* the cursor is moved away. The `onclick` event seems to negate the `onmouseout` event.

If you have any suggestions, please post revised code to codepen; it would be greatly appreciated! [Here is the code.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jkhrg)

```
<html><head><title>Title</title>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function changeContent1()
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='<a href="#" onmouseout="changeContentBack1()" style="text-decoration:none"><div style="background:black;color:white;width:450px;height:203px">THIS TEXT APPEARS ON CLICK OR ROLLOVER</div>'
    }
  </SCRIPT>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function changeContentBack1()
    {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML='<a href="#" onmouseover="changeContent1()" style="text-decoration:none"><div style="background:red;color:white;width:450px;height:203px">ORIGINAL TEXT</div></a>'
    }
  </SCRIPT>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="width:450px;float:left">This is the section title. <a href="#" onclick="changeContent1()"><a href="#" onclick="changeContent1()">Click for more info</a><br><br>
        <div id="myDiv"><a href="#" onmouseover="changeContent1()" style="text-decoration:none">
            <div style="background:red;color:white;width:450px;height:203px">ORIGINAL TEXT
            </div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Add the code to the question.

Comment: is there a reason you don't use jQuery?

Comment: Does the content actually need to change or does it just need to look like it changed?  In other words, could you not use CSS to hide/unhide the two "states" of the div?

Answer (score 0):

I added `onmouseout="changeContentBack1()"` to your link on your code pen and it works fine.

http://cdpn.io/ciHek

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ciHek

On a side note you might want to clean up your HTML and validate it.  I'm seeing a lot of missing or out of place tags.